# Django Tag App, defining a heterogeneous ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: python, django, generics, database-design, django-models

I'm working on building a tag system similar to what stackoverflow uses. A tag consist of a name and a collection of model instances that are associated with that tag. I can't find any documentation on how to declare this type of many to many relationship. Typically its just ManyToMany(model-name) but I have many models I want in this collection. Does anyone have any pointers or resources that may be useful?

Comment: Why don't you make a separate m2m relation for each model you want to connect with tags?

Comment: I don't want to create the dependence between the models and the tag model. If I add a new model to my system I don't want to have to add a new field to the tag application.

Comment: @Mike Are you using a module like `django-taggit` or `django-tagging` or just own code?

Comment: I'm trying to roll my own system.

Comment: @grosshat I gave taggit a try and it works great. Thanks for the recomendation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) to do this. There is even an example of doing tags with it in the documentation on that page. You probably will not be able to use a typical ManyToMany field, and instead, create a tagged model instead, that has a ForeignKey to your Tag model, and a GenericForeignKey.

Comment: It does give an example of a tagged item but I think my idea of how to implement may be a little different. Say for example there was a tag 'FOO'. In my proposed implementation the tag 'Foo' would be one entry in my table. It contains a many to many relationship with all the model instances that reference this tag. So if I wanted to find all model instances that reference 'FOO' I could just do Tag.objects.get(name='FOO').references.all() In the version in the docs if 4 objects referenced the 'FOO' tag then there would be 4 entries in the tagged_item table.

Comment: A Many-To-Many Relationship implicitly creates a table that has a foreign key to each side of the relationship. Basically, what I'm saying is that you need to explicitly create that table instead. You can still have a Tag table, but you also need to create a TaggedItem table too.